# How to return a temp table from a stored procedure to be used in a C# datareader?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I have the following stored procedure (T-SQL) and I'd like to call it using `command.ExecuteReader` in C# code so that I can loop through any errors raised **OR** call it from SQL directly.

However, I am not sure how to get the temp table to be returned - I just get a "0" back?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE validate
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ValidationResults TABLE
  ROWNUM int,
  ATP varchar(max),
  ATD varchar(max),
  ERROR varchar(max)
  )
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO @ValidationResults
  SELECT ROWNUM, ATP, ATD, 'ATP must be two characters'
  FROM cb with (TABLOCKX)
  WHERE LEN(ATP) <> 2

  RETURN SELECT * FROM @ValidationResults   
END
GO
```

Comment: Show us the C# code reading the data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use return, just select rows from `@ValidationResults`. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19010/Executing-Stored-Procedure-with-Data-Reader) may help you to get data from stored procedure.

[Here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html) is another useful article

Comment: DOH! How simple - I was presuming that to return data you needed to "return" something! lol
The datareader is no real issue, since now it's just a sproc instead of a select.